# Android Layout: Align a separator/divider

Tags: alignment, android-linearlayout, separator

I would need to align a separator/divider line in the midlle of each Layout. 
i tried do it but i can't to cross the separators.
I need to divide by group!

like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/thpWi.png

this is my:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/osP6P.jpg

here is my code:

```html
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/report_main_gradient"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="290dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_8">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Representante"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Cliente"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Sub Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPositivacao"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Positivação"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_50"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_h6_size" />
                    <View
                        android:background="@drawable/line_gradient"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPositivacao"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_8">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="330dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Representante"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Sub Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="Evolução"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_50"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_h6_size" />
                    <View
                        android:background="@drawable/line_gradient"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_8">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Comissão"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Vendas"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="MKT"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Sub Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Outros"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_50"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_h6_size" />
                    <View
                        android:background="@drawable/line_gradient"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_8">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Representante"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_artists" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Sub Brand"
                                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_s_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="Objetivo"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_50"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_h6_size" />
                    <View
                        android:background="@drawable/line_gradient"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

report_main_gradient.xml

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#175375"
        android:endColor="#1e2c3b"
        android:gradientRadius="600"
        android:startColor="#357194"
        android:type="radial" >
    </gradient>

</shape>
```

line_gradient.xml

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#175375"
        android:endColor="#357194"
        android:gradientRadius="600"
        android:startColor="#c5c5c5"
        android:type="radial" >
    </gradient>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

[See Image (Use View for sepration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZBYA.png)

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Playlist"
                   android:textSize="25sp"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

           </LinearLayout>

           <View
               android:layout_width="1dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#000"/>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:orientation="vertical">


               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:orientation="vertical">

                       <ImageView
                           android:layout_width="50dp"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Artists"
                           android:textSize="25sp"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                   </LinearLayout>

                   <View
                       android:layout_width="1dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:background="#000"/>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:orientation="vertical">
                       <ImageView
                           android:layout_width="50dp"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Albums"
                           android:textSize="25sp"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                   </LinearLayout>

               </LinearLayout>

               <View
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="1dp"
                   android:background="#000"/>

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:orientation="vertical">
                       <ImageView
                           android:layout_width="50dp"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Genres"
                           android:textSize="25sp"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                   </LinearLayout>

                   <View
                       android:layout_width="1dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:background="#000"/>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:orientation="vertical">
                       <ImageView
                           android:layout_width="50dp"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Songs"
                           android:textSize="25sp"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                   </LinearLayout>

               </LinearLayout>


           </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Videos"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Photos"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```